# Проблема с формулами в Excel

Tags: excel

Я не могу расписать нужную мне формулу так, чтобы Excel её понял, помогите(

1. Внести в таблицу начальные значения для параметра С (значение равно 6,5) и цены (значение равно 2,8).
2. Заполнить временной столбец n значениями от 0 до 100.
3. Произвести по формуле расчет величины динамики установления равновесия 
   Yn+1=YnC exp(-Yn)

Comment: Не получается что? п.1? п.3? Или ничего не получается?
Внести 6,5 в одну ячейку, 2,8 в другую. В столбце заполнить ячейки от 0 до 100.
Дальше непонятно: что есть Y в Вашем задании?

Comment: не получается п.3
http://fotki.yandex.ru/users/dublegame/view/914219/?page=0
вот картинка, я не могу формулу написать(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ссылаясь на картинку формула написана следующим образом:

> *ячейка f3:* =B7
>
> *ячейка f4:* =F3*$B$3*exp(-F3)
>
> *ячейка f5:* =F4*$B$3*exp(-F4)
>
> *ячейка f6:* =F5*$B$3*exp(-F5)
>
> ...
>
> и так далее, тянешь за квадратный уголок последнюю ячейку до конца.